# Is there a bug in Google docs add-on authorization popup?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Since last week we start seeing a bug when re-validating an add-on security in Google docs.

Steps to reproduce :

- given that I have a Google docs document, and I have installed an add-on
- when the add-on version changes I must accept again the security permission for that add-on
- Google docs shows a small popup : updated add-on / a script attached to this document needs your permission to run
- I click continue, and I except to see a popup prompting me to choose the permissions to validate

  BUT
- instead  I get Google docs displayed in the permission popup, embedded inside Google docs

see attached screenshot for this weird effect

The consequence is I cannot use the add-on, except by reinstalling it completely.

[image: permission validation replaced by parent window]

Comment: I think this is not a topic for so, but rather for Google's issue tracker. After all, we are not Google Support

Comment: Actually Google sends the developers to stackoverflow for community assistance. They have an issue tracker, but you cannot create tickets.

Comment: we still are not Google Support, even if Google - or any company - tries to claim as much. If you have a Google bug to report, you report it to people who work there, not an unaffiliated website. And yes, Google has a public issue tracker that you can file bugs on.